# error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, header-files, stdafx.h

I have a project, originally developed on Microsoft Visual C++ . NET, Version 7.0.9466 and it works very well. I tried to use MS 2013 to run my project, and when I try to build the project, I have this error menssage:

> error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?

Some actions that I already did:

- I Selected the option "Use(/Yu)" on Precompiled Header in *PropertyPages-> C/C++ -> Precompiled Header*
- I Set the Precompiled Header File to *stdafx.h*
- I put `#include "stdafx.h"` at the beginning of the .cpp file
- I had to change `#include "stdafx.h"` to `#include "../stdafx.h"` because I had this error message:

> IntelliSense: cannot open source file "stdafx.h"

Here is the .cpp file where I have this message error

```html
#include "../stdafx.h"
#include "timedmsgbox.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// CDlgTimedMessageBox
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CMapPtrToPtr  CDlgTimedMessageBox::m_mapTimerIdToClassMe;
CCriticalSection CDlgTimedMessageBox::m_sectMap;
extern BOOL AFXAPI AfxIsDescendant(HWND hWndParent, HWND hWndChild);

// the static one to call the messagebox with one line
UINT CDlgTimedMessageBox::TimedMessageBox(UINT flags, LPCTSTR ptszMessage, LPCTSTR ptszTitle, 
      DWORD dwTimeout, UINT dDefaultReturn,
      LPCTSTR ptszMessageTimer, HWND hwndParent, BOOL *pbStoppedByUser)
{
 CDlgTimedMessageBox  msgBox(flags, ptszMessage, ptszTitle, 
         dwTimeout, dDefaultReturn, 
         ptszMessageTimer, hwndParent);

 return msgBox.ShowMessageBox(pbStoppedByUser);
}

CDlgTimedMessageBox::CDlgTimedMessageBox(UINT flags, 
        LPCTSTR ptszMessage, LPCTSTR ptszTitle, 
        DWORD dwTimeout, UINT dDefaultReturn,
        LPCTSTR ptszMessageTimer, 
        HWND hwndParent)
{
 m_hParent   = hwndParent;
 m_Message   = ptszMessage;
 m_Title    = ptszTitle;
 m_flags    = flags;
 m_dwTimeout   = dwTimeout-1;
 m_MessageTimer  = ptszMessageTimer;
 m_DefaultReturn  = dDefaultReturn;
 
 m_hMsgBox   = NULL;
 m_hStaticText  = NULL;
 m_hDefaultButton = NULL;
 m_bRunning   = FALSE;
 m_bStoppedByTimer = FALSE;

 if( !m_hParent )
 {
  CWnd *m_pParent = AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd();
  m_hParent = m_pParent->m_hWnd;
 }
}

CDlgTimedMessageBox::~CDlgTimedMessageBox()
{
}

#pragma warning( push)
#pragma warning (disable : 4312) // conversion to type of greater size
UINT CDlgTimedMessageBox::ShowMessageBox(BOOL *pbStoppedByUser)
{
 // start timer 
 CDlgTimedMessageBox::m_sectMap.Lock();
 {
  m_idTimer = (UINT)::SetTimer(NULL, 0, 1000, (TIMERPROC) CDlgTimedMessageBox::GlobalTimerProc);
  CDlgTimedMessageBox::m_mapTimerIdToClassMe.SetAt((void*)m_idTimer, this);
 }
 CDlgTimedMessageBox::m_sectMap.Unlock();
 
 // show MessageBox
 m_bRunning = TRUE;
 m_dwStarted = ::GetTickCount();
 
 m_CurrentMessage = m_Message;
 if( !m_MessageTimer.IsEmpty() )
 {
  CString second;
  second.Format(m_MessageTimer, (m_dwTimeout+1)/1000);
  m_CurrentMessage.Format("%s%s", m_Message, second);
 }
 UINT erg = ::MessageBox(m_hParent, m_CurrentMessage, m_Title, m_flags);
 m_bRunning = FALSE;

 CDlgTimedMessageBox::m_sectMap.Lock();
 {
  ::KillTimer(NULL, m_idTimer);
  m_idTimer = 0;
  CDlgTimedMessageBox::m_mapTimerIdToClassMe.RemoveKey((void*)m_idTimer);
 }
 CDlgTimedMessageBox::m_sectMap.Unlock();

 if( pbStoppedByUser )
  *pbStoppedByUser = !m_bStoppedByTimer;
 
 return erg;
}
#pragma warning( pop )

void CALLBACK CDlgTimedMessageBox::GlobalTimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uiMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime)
{
 //TRACE("Global timer with id=%u\n", idEvent);
 
 CDlgTimedMessageBox *pMe = NULL;
 
 // Find the corresponding class by the timer-id
 CDlgTimedMessageBox::m_sectMap.Lock();
 {
  CDlgTimedMessageBox::m_mapTimerIdToClassMe.Lookup((void*)idEvent, (void *&) pMe);
 } 
 CDlgTimedMessageBox::m_sectMap.Unlock();
 
 if( pMe!=NULL )
  pMe->LocalTimerProc();
}

void CDlgTimedMessageBox::LocalTimerProc(void)
{
 //TRACE("Local timer with id=%u (%s)\n", m_idTimer, m_Title);

 if( !m_bRunning )
  return;

 // lookup the handles 
 GetWindowHandles();


 if( !m_hStaticText || !m_hMsgBox )
  return;

 DWORD now = GetTickCount()-m_dwStarted;
 
 if( now >= (m_dwTimeout) )
 {
  // done with the box
  m_bStoppedByTimer = TRUE;
  ::PostMessage(m_hMsgBox, WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM) m_DefaultReturn, (LPARAM) m_hDefaultButton);
 }
 else
 {
  m_CurrentMessage = m_Message;
 
  // not done: set text again
  if( !m_MessageTimer.IsEmpty() )
  {
   CString second;
   second.Format(m_MessageTimer, (100+m_dwTimeout-now)/1000);
   m_CurrentMessage.Format("%s%s", m_Message, second);
  }
  ::SetWindowText(m_hStaticText, m_CurrentMessage);
 } 
}

void CDlgTimedMessageBox::GetWindowHandles(void)
{
 HWND  hWnd;
 CWnd  *pWnd;
 CString  title;
 CPtrList allButtons;

 //
 // Handle of the messageBox
 //
 if( !m_hMsgBox )
 {
  hWnd = ::GetWindow(::GetDesktopWindow(), GW_CHILD);
  while( (hWnd!=NULL) && (m_hMsgBox==NULL) )
  {
   pWnd = CWnd::FromHandle(hWnd);
   pWnd->GetWindowText(title);

   if( AfxIsDescendant(m_hParent, hWnd) && ::IsWindowVisible(hWnd) && (m_Title.CompareNoCase(title)==0) )
   {
    m_hMsgBox = hWnd;
    break;
   }
   
   hWnd = ::GetWindow(hWnd, GW_HWNDNEXT);
  }
 }

 //
 // Handle of the static text
 // TODO only if text-replace is needed
 //
 if( m_hMsgBox && !m_hStaticText )
 {
  // not sure if this will work always
  // under Win2000 it did
  //m_hStaticText = ::GetDlgItem(m_hMsgBox, 0xFFFF);

  // not sure, so lets find it dynamically!

  char  className[_MAX_PATH];
  CString  classNameOk("STATIC");
  LONG  id;

  hWnd = ::GetWindow(m_hMsgBox, GW_CHILD);
  while( (hWnd!=NULL) && (m_hStaticText==NULL) )
  {
   id = ::GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_ID);
   
   // small ids only for buttons
   if( id > IDHELP )
   {
    if( ::GetClassName(hWnd, className, _MAX_PATH) )
    {

     // looking only for a static 
     if( classNameOk.CompareNoCase(className) == 0 )
     {
      // not check the text
      pWnd = CWnd::FromHandle(hWnd);
      pWnd->GetWindowText(title);
      
      if( m_CurrentMessage.CompareNoCase(title) == 0 )
      {
       m_hStaticText = hWnd;
       break;
      }

     }
    }
   }
   else
   {
    allButtons.AddTail(hWnd);
   }

   hWnd = ::GetWindow(hWnd, GW_HWNDNEXT);
  }

 }

 //
 // Handle of the default button
 //
 if( m_hMsgBox && !m_hDefaultButton )
 {
  m_hDefaultButton = ::GetDlgItem(m_hMsgBox, m_DefaultReturn);
  
  // Problem: 
  // if generated with MB_OK the button has NOT IDOK, but IDCANCEL !!
  // then lets take the first button we find !
  // (with and IDCANCEL this works, because it is the only button
  // if this problem encounters also with 2 buttons, I have no chance 
  // to find out which one is the better one!)
  while( allButtons.GetCount()>0 && !m_hDefaultButton )
  {
   m_hDefaultButton = (HWND) allButtons.GetHead();
   allButtons.RemoveHead();
   
   if( m_hDefaultButton )
    m_DefaultReturn = ::GetWindowLong(m_hDefaultButton, GWL_ID);
  }
 }
}
```

and here is the stdafx.h file

```html
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently,
// but are changed infrequently

#pragma once

#ifndef VC_EXTRALEAN
#define VC_EXTRALEAN  // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
#endif

// Modify the following defines if you have to target a platform prior to the ones specified below.
// Refer to MSDN for the latest info on corresponding values for different platforms.
#ifndef WINVER    // Allow use of features specific to Windows 95 and Windows NT 4 or later.
//#define WINVER 0x0400  // Change this to the appropriate value to target Windows 98 and Windows 2000 or later.
#define WINVER 0x0602       // SMS2014XXXX alteração para funcionar windows 8
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT  // Allow use of features specific to Windows NT 4 or later.
//#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400  // Change this to the appropriate value to target Windows 98 and Windows 2000 or later.
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0602       // SMS2014XXXX alteração para funcionar windows 8
#endif      

#ifndef _WIN32_WINDOWS  // Allow use of features specific to Windows 98 or later.
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0410 // Change this to the appropriate value to target Windows Me or later.
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_IE   // Allow use of features specific to IE 4.0 or later.
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0400 // Change this to the appropriate value to target IE 5.0 or later.
#endif

#define _ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS // some CString constructors will be explicit

// turns off MFC's hiding of some common and often safely ignored warning messages
#define _AFX_ALL_WARNINGS

#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions
#include <afxdisp.h>        // MFC Automation classes
#include <afxdtctl.h>  // MFC support for Internet Explorer 4 Common Controls

#ifndef _AFX_NO_AFXCMN_SUPPORT
#include <afxcmn.h>   // MFC support for Windows Common Controls
#endif // _AFX_NO_AFXCMN_SUPPORT

#include <afxdhtml.h>
```

I am new on visual studio and I have no ideia what's is wrong on all of this. Someone could help me with it?

Comment: You'll have to change the /Yc and /Yu compile options on every file.  This is unpractical, just use plain "stdafx.h" so the compile options are good.  And either move the .h file or use the compiler's Additional Include Directories setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a confusion between intellisense and the compiler.

You should be able to work around it by adding `$(ProjectDir)` to the `Additional Include Directories` option for the application and replacing the `"..\StdAfx.h"` with `"StdAfx.h"` as intellisense should now start picking up the path.

Comment: This did not help in VS 2015. I added $(ProjectDir) to the "Include Directories" under VC++ Directories in the project properties, but I still get the same error for #include "..\..\stdafx.h". I guess the only workaround is to use filters instead of subfolders for C++ code files.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this since i read this post when struggling with adding .pch to a project.

when adding .pch to an exisiting project:
if you have a /include and a /src dir structure, it might not work, unless you place the "pch.h" and "pch.cpp" in the same dir /src.

Also: mark the "pch.cpp" as /Yc - create, and in the .cpp files you want to use the .pch set them to Yu - use.

#include "pch.h" as the first #include in the .cpp

NB. You need to set "not using precompiled headers" to all .cpp files that doesnt include them.. yes, it IS a hassle.

both "additional include directories" and the general "include directories" under VC++ where set to my /include, and ofcourse /src was in "source directories"
Originally i wanted the pch.h and pch.cpp to be in /include/pch/ or /src/pch/
and that should work. But i've had enough pain now and just placed them both in /src/ - which does work.

( Visual Studio 2019 )