# C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "pch.h"' to your source? Even though it is there

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdk, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer this unreal engine 3 game and dump the SDK (not going to say what game just in case), and I am getting this error for every SDK `.cpp` SDK file:

`C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "pch.h"' to your source?`

Though in every file it's erroring in, it has `#include "../pch.h"` at the very top, and I know it's the correct directory because even Visual Studio intellisense is finding the `pch.h` file[image]

Comment: Do you have a `pch.cpp` file in your project? And, if so, is set to **create** the precompiled header (all other files should be set to use it)?

Comment: Another reason not to use precompiled headers.  You should profile the build times, with and without pch.  Is it significant?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include the stdafx.h from the root directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434123/how-to-include-the-stdafx-h-from-the-root-directory) Also you can maybe follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460176/4074081) answer to be able to use `#include "pch.h"` instead of `#include "../pch.h"`

Comment: And of course you can just diasble usage of precompiled header in the project settings: the code should compile, just slower.

Comment: Yeah I just chose to not include the precompiled header and go on with life without it, thanks for responding!